# Why Unix wildcard "*" does not include ".*"?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, wildcard

Consider a directory with only one file `.foo`. Then `rm -rf *` won't remove the `.foo`; only `rm -rf .*` will. Why is this the case? (I guess this has something to do with the default `.` and `..`, but what's the design rationale? I tend to leave behind the dot files when they are supposed to be removed.)

Comment: It is an old convention: file names starting with a dot are "hidden" to the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be matched explicitly, unless the shell option `dotglob` is set. When matching a file name, the slash character must always be matched explicitly. In other cases, the ‘.’ character is not treated specially.

As for the rationale, I can only guess.  I imagine it's so that you don't accidentally manipulate files you didn't know existed (remember that `ls` doesn't display `.foo`).

Answer (score 13):

According to Rob Pike, the whole notion that files whose name start with a dot should be "hidden" [was the result of a software bug](https://plus.google.com/101960720994009339267/posts/R58WgWwN9jp).

In particular, he says:

> First, a bad precedent was set. A lot of other lazy programmers introduced bugs by making the same simplification. Actual files beginning with periods are often skipped when they should be counted.
>
> Second, and much worse, the idea of a "hidden" or "dot" file was created. [...]
>
> I'm pretty sure the concept of a hidden file was an unintended consequence. It was certainly a mistake.

Historical accidents aside, it is a good conservative design decision to exclude hidden files from wildcard expansion. Otherwise commands like `rm *` would have the potential to do a lot more damage than what was intended by the user.

Answer (score 3):

This is because files prefixed with `.` are normally hidden, and are not part of a normal globbing expansion.  This means that you don't get messed-up globs in directories that contain control files or directories (*eg* `.svn`).  When you use `*`, you generally intend it to expand to normal files.

Answer (score 1):

The design rationale behind this is that, for example `.foo`, is a hidden file. a volatile operation on the entire directory could end up doing more damage that what was intended.